# EndroidQrCodeBundle doesn't work on my server

Tags: symfony, debian, twig, qr-code

I'm using [QrCodeBundle](https://github.com/endroid/EndroidQrCodeBundle) to generate QrCodes inside my twig. It works fine locally and on dev server using Ubuntu but not on my prod server using Debian.

This is how I call the bundle inside my twig:

```
<img src="{{ asset(qrcode_url(app.request.scheme ~'://' ~ app.request.httpHost ~ ' ' ~ test, extension='png', size=90)) }}"/></img>
```

If anyone already used this bundle any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you find some error messages in some logs? Can yoi debug enabling the dev sf env on debian server?

Comment: Che for ext-gd lbrary in the php conf